# RC5 Angular2 route default component

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing, angular2-template

I have existing `PHP` website, which I start adding angular2 component to.

I have added router script, to help load different component by its url.

When I navigate away from the component page, I get following error `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'dashboard'`

I understand, that I need to create another component to make this error disappear. But I don't want to create another component, because there are so many pages, I would end up creating component for each page.

So I wanted to ask, how to make 1 default component, which will pickup if no component was available OR how can I just make this error disappear, so it does not trigger if it cant found any router or component for that path.

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {TestComponent} from "./test/test.component";


const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'search', component: TestComponent }
];


export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may add a `wildcard route` which will redirect to a default component if route does not match.

```
 { path: 'default', component: DefaultComponent },
 { path: '**', redirectTo: '/default' }
```

So if the route does not match your default component will be loaded in the router outlet.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I use this as default route:

```
{ path: '', component: Home, text: 'Home' }
```

and this is my full routes:

```
export const routes: TextRoute[] = [
    { path: '', component: Home, text: 'Home' },
    { path: 'accordion', component: AccordionDemo, text: 'Accordion' },
    { path: 'alert', component: AlertDemo, text: 'Alert' },
    { path: 'buttons', component: ButtonsDemo, text: 'Buttons' },
    { path: 'carousel', component: CarouselDemo, text: 'Carousel' },
    { path: 'collapse', component: CollapseDemo, text: 'Collapse' },
    { path: 'dropdown', component: DropdownDemo, text: 'Dropdown' },
    { path: 'pagination', component: PaginationDemo, text: 'Pagination' },
    { path: 'popover', component: PopoverDemo, text: 'Popover' },
    { path: 'progressbar', component: ProgressbarDemo, text: 'Progressbar' },
    { path: 'rating', component: RatingDemo, text: 'Rating' }
];

export const AppRoutes = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true });
```

Check out my [learning angular2](https://github.com/beginor/learning-angular2) project at github, stars are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Im too new to comment, my question is if you are using express backend? app.use() might be able to save you some trouble. instead of declaring the routes try in app.js

```
var routes = require('routes');
app.use('/name-of-url', routes )
```

then in routes

```
    router.get('name-of-url', function(res,req,next){
     res.sendFile(path to php file to serve)
})
```

You may also need to change your express templating engine to php, not entirely sure.